# Flip taskbar order in Windows 10 / 11 in vertical mode (switch start button with clock)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-11, themes

Obviously Microsoft with a passion doesn't let us fully customize the taskbar. Since I have a ultrawide monitor, I need my taskbar on the side of the screen. But now my start button is at the top.

Is there any hack or tool or virtual taskbar replacement out there, that can e.g. reorder or switch the location of the start button with the location of the system tray / clock menu?

---

I remember there was some kind of 3rd party app that would duplicate your main full taskbar on other displays. So maybe a complete replacement can be done; a 3rd party virtual taskbar

Comment: Try one of the Start Menu replacement Apps. What you want does not work with Windows 11

Comment: Start menu replacements only change the icon and menu, not position on taskbar AFAIK. ...Wouldn't it be possible to completely hide the M$ taskbar and replace it with a custom 3rd party program that does the same functionality via shell scripts and shortcuts? (asking because I don't know if all the main features can be covered like that) (also for the record, I recommend fully switching to linux instead of ever installing windows 11)

Comment: With Windows 11 for sure, you cannot flip the task bar the way you want. Windows 10 is the same, I am fairly sure as well.